# How the user id set as session during login in codeigniter and acess this userid to several function?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

The **user id** set as session during login in codeigniter and access this **user id** to several function? The direct access of url must be prevented.

```
public function loginaction()

  {

        $this->load->library('session');    

                        $a=$this->input->post('email');
            $b=trim($this->input->post('password'));
                        $b1=md5($b);
                        $c=1;
//                        echo $a;
//                        echo $b1;
                        $data=$this->userdata->userlogin($a,$b1,$c);
//                        print_r($data);
//                        exit;
            if($data)
                        {

                    echo true;
                    foreach ($data as $login)
                    {
                        $uid=$this->session->set_userdata('logId',$login->usr_id);
                             //redirect(base_url() . 'main/userhome' . $uid, 'refresh');    
                    }
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Invalid username or password..!!!!";
                                  $a=$this->input->post('email');

            }
  }
```

This is my session setting code. i want this userid in the home page.how can i get it?

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{


    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url()?>Main/loginaction",
            data:{email:document.getElementById('email').value,password:document.getElementById('password').value},
            success: function(data){

        alert(data);

                if(data==true)
                window.location.replace('<?php echo base_url()?>Main/userhome');

            }
            });     
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A session, as far as CodeIgniter is concerned, is simply an array containing the following information:

The user's unique Session ID (this is a statistically random string with very strong entropy, hashed with MD5 for portability, and regenerated (by default) every five minutes)
The user's IP Address
The user's User Agent data (the first 120 characters of the browser data string)
The "last activity" time stamp.
The above data is stored in a cookie as a serialized array with this prototype:

```
[array]
(
     'session_id'    => random hash,
     'ip_address'    => 'string - user IP address',
     'user_agent'    => 'string - user agent data',
     'last_activity' => timestamp
)
```

Retrieving Session Data:

```
$this->session->userdata('session_id');
```

One thing You should must use:
->To import session library manually

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

->OR add the 'session' in application/config/autoload.php like this:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database,session');
```

NOTE: you can include libraries directly like comma separated value.

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->session->set_userdata('user_id', $value);
//to get
$this->session->userdata('user_id);
```

Comment: is this value is available for entire project?

Comment: Where ever your session class is available.

Answer (score 0):

I Guess you are using database to store your sessions.

Now to access the data in sessions:
 First initialize session library:

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

Then

```
echo $this->session->userdata('id');
```

Also if you want to print all user session data then you could do this:

```
echo $this->session->all_userdata();
```

hope this helps :)

And to use this you for entire project you can create a Base Controller and initialize session library there, then extend all your controllers to that Base Controller.

You could do like:

```
<?php
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    $this->load->library('session');

  }
```